Inserting a class in std::map using only move constructor
I have a class that doesn't implement neither a default constructor, nor a copy constructor, just a move constructor, and inside a function I want to insert a new instance of this class into a std::map, but when I use std::move for that, my instance still gets destroyed at the end of the function scope, isn't it supposed to move the ownership of the instance to the container ?

class Server {
  public:

    friend class Client;
    class Client {
      public:
        Client() = delete;
        Client(const Client &) = delete;
        Client(Client &&) = default;
        ~Client() {
          ::close(m_fd);
        }
        Client & operator =(const Client &) = delete;
        Client & operator =(Client &&) = default;
    
      private:
        Client(int fd, const in_addr & addr) : m_fd(fd), m_addr(addr) {}
      
        int m_fd;
        in_addr addr;
    };

  private:
    void m_acceptClient() {
      sockaddr_in addr;
      socklen_t addrLen = sizeof(addr);
      int fd = accept4(
          m_fd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&addr), &addrLen, SOCK_NONBLOCK
      );

      if (fd == -1) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN)
          return;
        m_throwError(AcceptException());
        return;
      }

      auto client = Client(fd, addr.sin_addr);
      m_clients.emplace(fd, std::move(client));

      // client gets destroyed here
      //
      // I also tried to do
      // m_clients.emplace(fd, Client(fd, addr.sin_addr))
      // but the client also gets destroyed immediately
      // what I want to do is being able to insert a new Client
      // into the map without having to implement copy semantics for it
      // because it doesn't make sense to have them in this case
    }
    int m_fd;


Default move for int or other trivial types is equivalent to copy. You have to implement it yourself and zero (or whatever is the correct invalid value for file descriptors) the value from original object.

@Yksisarvinen I don't really care about the fd being copied, I just want my Client to get instanciated only once and moved into the map (and not getting destroyed at the end of the function)

I think you got mislead by the name "move constructor". Move operations don't actually move anything in memory, at best what they can do is implement a swap of two pointers, so that moved-to object has what moved-from object had. For trivial types like int the default move operation is just a copy. =default won't do anything good here, you need to actually implement move operations that will set fd to -1 in moved-from object.

client is getting moved, its just that all objects are destroyed at the end of the function and client was declared in the function. Your move operations need to set the instance they move from into a state where it being destroyed does not cause an issue.  The contents of client though were moved into the map.
If you don't want that to happen what you can do is directly construct the object in the map using the std::piecewise_construct_t tagged overload of emplace instead like
void m_acceptClient() {
  sockaddr_in addr;
  socklen_t addrLen = sizeof(addr);
  int fd = accept4(
      m_fd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&addr), &addrLen, SOCK_NONBLOCK
  );

  if (fd == -1) {
    if (errno == EAGAIN)
      return;
    m_throwError(AcceptException());
    return;
  }

  m_clients.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 
                    std::forward_as_tuple(fd), 
                    std::forward_as_tuple(fd, addr.sin_addr));
}


For one thing, you're using emplace incorrectly: if you just std::move an existing object, emplace isn't really needed.
However, coming back to your question: std::move doesn't move "ownership", it moves the data. There are still two objects involved (the one that is moved from, and the one that is moved to), so your temporary client gets destroyed.
Which also means you're closing the fd when moving it into the container, and a second timer when you destruct the container. You need to implement a better move and destruct on your object to fix this.
Something similar to:
int m_fd=-1;

Client& operator=(Client&& other)
{
   std::swap(m_fd, other.m_fd);
   addr=other.addr;
   return *this;
}

Client(Client&& other)
{
   operator=(std::move(other));
}

~Client()
{
   if (m_fd!=-1) close(m_fd);
}

